# How to remove marker background while implementing subclass of ItemizedOverlay?

Tags: android, google-maps, itemizedoverlay

I'm working with Google-maps, I added some points to map. I use this picture as marker:[image]

Below there is what I have now:

[image: How it looks now]

You may notice that this picture has white background and it doesn't look OK on the map. Is there a way to remove white background (and shadow of that lollipop)? I believe it would look much better than.

Maybe, that would be useful, I post source of my subclass below:

```
    class PointsInMoskow extends ItemizedOverlay{
    private List<List<Address>> convertedAddresses=new ArrayList<List<Address>>();
    private List<OverlayItem> points=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Drawable marker;

    public PointsInMoskow(Drawable marker){
        super(marker);
        this.marker=marker;

        try {
            convertedAddresses.add(geocoder.getFromLocationName("Москва, м.Фили", 2));
            convertedAddresses.add(geocoder.getFromLocationName("Москва, м.Площадь Революции", 2));
            convertedAddresses.add(geocoder.getFromLocationName("Москва, м. Калужская", 2));
            int latitude;
            int longitude;
            for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                List<Address> addressList=(List<Address>)convertedAddresses.get(i);
                if(addressList!=null && addressList.size()>0){
                    latitude=(int)(addressList.get(0).getLatitude()*1000000);
                    longitude=(int)(addressList.get(0).getLongitude()*1000000);
                    points.add(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), "title", "snippet"));
                }
            }
            populate();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return points.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return points.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The image you are using uses opaque colors. In order for the map to show through the parts you want you will have to use transparency in the original image.

This isn't really a programming question, but there are lots of tutorials on how to do this

http://fabiovisentin.com/tutorial/gimp_transparent_image/gimp_how_to_make_transparent_image.asp

Another option would be to manipulate the image in Java, but it could be difficult to get the effect you want. You could load the image into a BitmapDrawable then manipulate it and set it as the marker.

- http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ultimate-image/
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html